# CSS add new Tag to html dynamically

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to add new tag in Html through CSS?

like for Jquery but translated in css:

```
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').wrap('<a href="#"/>');
```

Comment: You mean like this `$('div.ms-inputuserfield').wrap('<a href="#" style="color:red">Test</a>');` ?

Comment: noo i want to add html tag through CSS

Answer (score 1):

No, with CSS there is only one possibility - pseudo selectors `:after/:before` with 'content' property. But it wont add the element to the DOM, so it wont be possible to reference it from the javascript.

Comment: my requirement is replace the dropdown with radio buttons when the css replace no use of jquery..